# How to define a function to add the text "hello world\n" at the current buffer's cursor?

Tags: bash

Looking for this for years. I am going to be brave and ask.

```
(defun paste-hello-world ()
    (paste-raw-text-at-cursor "hello world\n")
)
```

Need something like the above. The place I work at has custom headers for their code, so I want write some shortcut to generate them.

Alternatively, is a way I way I can pipe bash output from a bash command to my active buffers cursor?

Googling this as very challenging, as most results just tell you how to copy-and-paste text using Emacs. Some hints on the jargon for googling this would also be appreciated,

Comment: Use function `insert`. But first read some of the manual (`C-h i`) Emacs Lisp Intro, to at least find out how to invoke a function in Elisp.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested `insert` should serve you for a few "shortcuts". Since it sounds like you want to auto-insert boilerplate you'll probably want something more powerful. The Emacs wiki [`has some options`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutomaticFileHeaders). Emacs comes with an [`auto-insert-mode`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoInsertMode). The package [`lice.el`](https://github.com/buzztaiki/lice-el) provides header templates for common licenses, and allows you to define your own custom file headers. A more powerful option would be a snippet framework like [`yasnippet`](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet) (which you could combine with `auto-insert-mode`). You could also look at [Insert boilerplate automatically when a new file is created](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/70412/insert-boilerplate-automatically-when-a-new-file-is-created), [Inserting/updating source file header comments](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/537/inserting-updating-source-file-header-comments) and [Template for new file](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/45629/template-for-new-file).